# Stored procedure for Repeater - Select columns from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a `Repeater` in Visual Studio (asp.net and c#). The thing is, I am not quite sure how to properly format my stored procedure.

Here is the error:

[image]

My goal is to have a `Repeater` display a label and textbox for each column in my table. The label must have the `DisplayName` from the database.

Here is my table, `FormField`, that I want to use for my `Repeater`.

[image]

So here is my idea for my stored procedure at the moment:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetFormFields]
        @TableName nvarchar,
        @EventId int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS MyColumn
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
      AND EventId = @EventId 
      AND Visible = 1
END
```

However this doesn't quite work, as I get errors at `EventId` and `Visible`:

> Invalid Column Name

So here is what I have in my C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Make label names diff
        //Control which columns are shown
        //Style the labels and textboxes to css
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(string));

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS MyColumn FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND EventId = @EventId AND Visible = 1");
                sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "FormField";
                sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "1";

                sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
                        tableRow["MyColumn"] = sqlReader["MyColumn"].ToString();
                        table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                    }

                    Repeater1.DataSource = table;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                }

                sqlConn2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My C# code implements the SQL without any stored procedure (still gets the same error about the columns not existing). Of course I want to add in the stored procedure once I get it to work, so this was for testing purposes.

And finally, here is the asp.net markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="repeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_repeater" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table and there is no such column `EventId` & `Visible` there. If I have understood you properly you want to display _DisplayName_ from your table based on condition then why you are querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table?

Comment: Yes I am just going to display DisplayName in the label for this example. Part of my reasoning for grabbing all columns is to be more flexible for future implementation (soon I want to add, edit, delete rows in FormField, which means I need to be able to manipulate every column in the table).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Right now, your parameter `@TableName` is **exactly 1 character** long ..... usually *not* what you want!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I will fix that.

Comment: @RockOn - I am still confused if you are storing the columns in table itself then why fetch the schema? Makes no sense.

Comment: I am probably confused on the matter of how to do it. I am going to be having a form builder on here eventually. This page though is going to just have the form itself, so my code should currently just grab all DisplayName rows and place it into the Repeater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, You are querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table and there is no such column `EventId` & `Visible` there. If I have understood you correctly you want to display `DisplayName` from your table based on condition then you can directly do it like this:-

```
SELECT DisplayName AS MyColumn
    FROM [Events2].dbo.[FormField]
    WHERE EventId = @EventId AND 
    Visible = 1
```